# Android get status bar positions (top or bottom of screen)

Tags: android

There are Android devices that have status bar at the bottom of the screen. So if I count absolute position including the height of status bar at these devices, the layout will be ruined.

Is there a way to determine the position of the status bar, if it's at the top of bottom of the screen?

Comment: Hey, you downvoter! What is your problem with my question? Care to emplain? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code works for me. I just found it from an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379423/figure-out-whether-status-bar-is-at-top-or-bottom).

```
public static int getTopStatusBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    return rect.top;
}
```

If result of this method is 0, it means the status bar is at the bottom, and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it can't be done. Their position is absolute. You can hide/unhide them. But you can't move them. You can however split them:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
Then this link shows you how you can hide/unhide some of the bars:
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the figure you linked only contains element names for colors. I don't really understand how I could you this to get the position of status bar.